# Arithmetic operators and regex

Tags: regular-expressions

Let $L$ be the language over the alphabet $\{0, 1, 2, 3, (,), +, -, *, /\}$, $L$ is the set of operations with correctly formatted natural numbers. A single number is considered to belong to $L$.

2 - - 3 is an incorrect expression, 2 + 3 is correct, 2 + (-3) is correct. 
Is it possible to write a regular expression for this language?  If not, why?

I think that it is not possible to write a regular expression for this language, because of the operator / we cannot write 2 / 0 for example and are more than a finite number combinations to make this possible. Is it correct?

Comment: Can you define the language $L$ in more detail?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible to be 2 * * 3 or 2 + + 5 for example. So it is not correct to repeat the some operator more than one

Comment: It's impossible to write a Regex for your problem since your language $L$ is a Context-Free Language, and thats without checking for edge cases like divide-by-zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined your language, but presumably
$$
L \cap [^*0+0](+0])^* = \{ [^n[0+0](+0])^n : n \geq 0 \},
$$
where I replaced parentheses with square brackets. The latter language is essentially $\{a^nb^n : n \ge 0 \}$ in disguise, and so isn't regular. It follows that $L$ isn't regular as well.